# How can I set the style of MFC project to Win95 classic?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I'm building a simple MDI MFC application with Visual Studio 2022 Community.
I've got a request to set the style of application as 'Win95 classic', but I can't find how.

I tried to find the phrase 'Win95 classic' on my environment but I couldn't.

I've heard that this can be done by programmatical way. Is it right? Which class and function should I use?

Comment: Probably going to have to start a project from scratch, referencing an incredibly outdated [version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/common-control-versions) of the common controls, and see if MFC is compatible with it (after you've managed to add MFC to the project). Chances are that it won't, so you're likely best off not using MFC altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming by "Win95 classic" you mean style is the old classic pré Windows XP common controls, you probably just need to proceed like this:

Find this piece of code (or something close to it) which should be somewhere in one of your header files (possibly in framework.h, but depending on the Visual Studio version, the project has been created with, it might be somewhere else):

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
#if defined _M_IX86
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_X64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#else
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#endif
#endif
```

and remove it alltogether.

Then your application should have the old ugly Windows look:

[image]

instead of the modern look:

[image]

Comment: It's very sad because I couldn't found that stuff of codes in my header files.

Comment: @RK_diamond so you ended up finding it?

Comment: No. I'm still finding how.